# Add "0" to the front of an integer

Tags: php

hi I'm generating an random integers using `mt_rand(1, 99999)` and if its not equal to 5 digits it will add 0 on the front of the integers.

here's my first try:

```
$random_number = mt_rand(1, 99999);
$ran_len = strlen($random_number);

while ($ran_len != 5 ) {
$add_ran_num = str_pad($random_number, 1, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
}

echo $add_ran_num;
```

Comment: Put `$ran_len = ...` in the loop or pad by the difference of 5.

Comment: Clearly cannot see a question.

Comment: this while does give a hell of an endless loop, doesn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `strlen` nor `while` loop for that :

```
$random_number = mt_rand(1, 99999);
$add_ran_num = str_pad($random_number, 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
echo $add_ran_num;
```

Answer (score 7):

```
printf('%05d', mt_rand(1, 99999));
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want

```
$random_number = str_pad(mt_rand(1, 99999), 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't update the value of `$ran_len`:

```
$random_number = mt_rand(1, 99999);
$ran_len = strlen($random_number);

while ($ran_len != 5 ) {    
    $add_ran_num = str_pad($random_number, 1, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $ran_len = strlen($random_number);//<---
}

echo $add_ran_num;
```

Thus the loop is infinite.